# How can I Get rid of the Forward slashes " \\ " in an IEnumerable List

Tags: c#, list, ienumerable

I have the Two List as Defined Below

```
IEnumerable<string> fileNames = new DirectoryInfo(Path)
  .EnumerateFiles("fileServer.config", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
  .Select(fi => fi.DirectoryName)
  .Select(dirPath => dirPath.Substring(Path.Length));


List<string> subFolderNames = fileNames.ToList();
```

However the Output of this subFolderNames  comes with a \\ infront of each element, like this

**\\ElementName**

How can I *get rid* of this **\\** ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically, you can `Trim` unwanted characters (which are directory separators):

```
   ...
   .Select(dirPath => dirPath
      .Substring(Path.Length)
      .TrimStart(Path.AltDirectorySeparatorChar, Path.DirectorySeparatorChar));
```

Or change `Substring` argument:

```
   ...
   .Select(dirPath => dirPath.Substring(Path.Length + 1));
```

However, if you want inmost directory name

```
   IEnumerable<string> fileNames = new DirectoryInfo(Path)
     .EnumerateFiles("fileServer.config", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
     .Select(fi => fi.Name);
```

Comment: #1 is the most beautiful solution